# lost files after git merge

Tags: git, merge

I had a feature branch F1. Someone did changes which do not belong to that feature. What has been done: We branched off F2 for that other feature. I deleted those changes on F1 and merged F1 to master (as this feature has been finished).
Now F2 is ready to test. As my development setup changed in the meantime, I created F2_ and merged F2 into it.
Now, files are missing. Some of the files I deleted from F1 once. So, I understand a bit why these files are missing now, but I don't have a clue how to retrieve them back...
The merge is clean from git side but not for me...
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your checked out F2_ with the missing files

```
git checkout F1 path/to/missing/file.txt path/to/missing/file2.txt path/to/anothermissing/file.txt
```

check you are happy, then commit